# Intersecting List with keys of Map

Tags: java, string, list, java-8, java-stream

We have a map of Student to record `Map<Student, StudentRecord>`.
Student class is as follows:

```
Student {
    String id;
    String grade;
    Int age; 
}
```

Additionally, we have a list of Student Id `(List<String>)` provided.
Using Java streams, what would be the most efficient way to filter out records of students whose Id exists in the provided list?
The expected outcome is the filtered list mapped against the Id(String) -  `<Map<Id, StudentRecord>>`

Comment: If the input is a `Map<Student,StudentRecord>`, how come the output is a `List<Map<Student,StudentRecord>>`? Shouldn't the output be a `Map<Student,StudentRecord>` where some of the entries are filtered out?

Comment: And anyway, before finding "the most efficient way", you should first try to find "a way". Have you tried anything? What's the concrete problem you faced?

Comment: Edited the question as per Eran's observation.Have never tried intersection using java streams.

Comment: So now is the right moment. Hint: don't think about it as "an intersection". Think about it as: I have a map, which is a collection of entries, and I only want some of them. And once I know the ones I want, I want to store them in another map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stream set of entries:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> list.contains(e.getKey()))
    .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

If you also want to map keys to `id` field, then:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> list.contains(e.getKey()))
    .collect(toMap(e -> e.getKey().getId(), Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd convert your `List` to a `Set`, to avoid linear search time:

```
List<String> ids = ...
Set<String> idsSet = new HashSet<>(ids);
```

Now, you can stream over the entries of the `Map`, filter out those having ids in the `List`/`Set`, and collect the remaining ones to an output `Map`:

```
Map<String,StudentRecord> filtered = 
    input.entrySet()
         .stream()
         .filter(e -> !idsSet.contains(e.getKey().getId()))
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().getId(),Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

Although other answers are correct but I think they are not more efficient since they use temporary memory or its complicity is not `o(n)`.

the other answer is like this:

```
provided.stream()
        .map(id -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(id, map.entrySet()
                    .stream().filter(st -> st.getKey().id == id)
                    .map(Map.Entry::getValue).findFirst()))
        .filter(simpleEntry ->simpleEntry.getValue().isPresent())
        .map(entry-> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue))
```